# How perform a update statement with odbc on asp mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, db2, odbc

I have an app that uses asp mvc 4 and DB2 DB, and sql instruction developed with odbc.

The problem is that I can't perform an insert, update and delete on the database. (I do not know how to do it).

I use the following pattern in select statement:

```
string query = "select login, name from user where login = dxfg"    
OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("credentials :)");
cn.Open();
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand (query,cn);
OdbcDataReader oa = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

But I don´t know how to perform other instructions, for example an update, insert or delete (and return to the controller method)

We appreciate your help or link reference.

Thanks.

Comment: Check this link out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tc47t75.aspx